# Unity says my Array index is out of range?

Tags: javascript, arrays, unity-game-engine

So Im trying to create a slot machine in Unity and I am receiving an error saying my Array index is out of range.  Here is a picture of the error.
If anyone could help me figure it out I would appreciate it.

```
#pragma strict

var id: int = -1; 
var GO: GameObject;
var mScript: master; // script

// 0=stopped 1, 2, 3, 4=spinning 5=finished
var stateWheel: int = 0;

var angleStart = 0.0;
var angleStop = 0.0;
var angT = 0.0;
var ang = 0.0;
var r = 0.0;
var angleRandom = 0.0;
var countFast: int;
var index: int = -1;

var totalFaster = 0.0;
var totalSlower = 0.0;


var t = 0.0;
var td = 0.0;

function Start (){
    GO = GameObject.Find("Master");
    mScript = GO.GetComponent (master);

    stateWheel = 0;
    angleStart = 0.0;
    angT = 0.0;
    t = 0.0;
} 

function Update () {    
     td = Time.deltaTime; // time since last Update
     t += td;

     switch (stateWheel) {
         case 0:
             initialize();
             return;
         case 1:
             rotateFaster();
             return;
        case 2:
             rotateFast();
             return;
        case 3:
             rotateSlower();
             return;
        case 4:
             rotateReverse();
             return;
        case 5:
             finished();
             return;
     }
 }

 function initialize() {

if (mScript.stateWheels[id] != 1) return;
mScript.stateWheels[id] = 0;

r = mScript.randomNo();
angleStop = 18.0*Mathf.RoundToInt(360.0*r/18.0);
if (angleStop >= 360) angleStop -= 360;
angleRandom = angleStop - angleStart;
if (angleRandom < 0) angleRandom += 360;

ang = 0.0;
stateWheel++;
 }

 function rotateFaster() {
     ang += 0.02;
     if (ang > 10) {
         var angleAdjust = (360 - 335) + (360 - 135);

         var a = angleAdjust + angleRandom;
         if (a >= 360) a -= 360;
         countFast = Mathf.RoundToInt(a/10) + 1;
         stateWheel++;
         return;
    }

    totalFaster += ang;
    if (totalFaster >= 360) totalFaster -= 360;
    angT += ang;
    if (angT >= 360) angT -= 360;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-angT, 0.0, 0.0);
}

function rotateFast() {
     countFast--;
     if (countFast == 0) stateWheel++;

     ang = 10;
    angT += ang;
     if (angT >= 360) angT -= 360;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-angT, 0.0, 0.0);
```

}

```
 function rotateSlower() {
     ang -= 0.1;
     if (ang < 0) {
         stateWheel++;
         return;
     }

     totalSlower += ang;
     if (totalSlower>= 360) totalSlower -= 360;
     angT += ang;
     if (angT >= 360) angT -= 360;
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-angT, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    function rotateReverse() {
     angT -= 0.4;
     if (angT < angleStop) {
          angT = Mathf.RoundToInt(angT);
          stateWheel++;
     }
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-angT, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

     function finished() {

      index = Mathf.RoundToInt(angT/18);
      if (index == 0) index += 20;
      angleStart = angT;
      stateWheel = 0;
     }
```

Comment: Too much code, where exactly is this error pointing to?

Comment: `id` is defined as `-1`, so what do you expect to access with `mScript.stateWheels[id]`?

Comment: above and `var index: int = -1;`

Comment: Sorry the errors were: IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range. wheelScript.initialize () (at ......wheelScript.js:75) and teh same error at ... wheelScript.js:53)

Comment: I assume that's exactly the line I pointed out. (I am not going to count the lines) So explain what you expect that line of code to do

Comment: I did that because Im waiting until mScript.stateWheels[id] is 1

Answer (score 0):

As many said in the comments, the problem is clearly because you set **id** to *-1* at line `var id: int = -1;` : an array start index is 0.

When you try to get an element of an array that doesn't exists (array is null, index < 0, or index >= array's length), you will get this error.